# How can I modify the script to search for root directory for jpg files

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

I am using vi and I am want to modify my existing script in such a way that it searches for .jpg files in the root directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR='/opt'

find $DIR -name '*.gif'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR='/'
find $DIR -name '*.jpg' -type f
```

Comment: By this he means:  

`find / -name *.jpg -type f` and be sure to execute as su (sudo)

Comment: It says "Permission denied"

Comment: Save the script as search.sh. Then switch to root and run it.

Comment: Where am I suppose to save it.? As i can't save it in root and it doesn't allow me to run from root as it says "Permission denied" even if I used chmod 777

Comment: -1, the argument that is the filename should always be quoted to prevent the glob from being expanded by the shell. If your current dir contains any JPG file the find command would not deliver any results.

Comment: @slhck I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With help from [this forum post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=483117):

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR = '/'
find $DIR -name ''*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]' -o -name '*.[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]'
```

This script will match all possible capitalizations of both JPEG file extensions.